# Como faço para arredondar um valor de 39,54 para 39

Tags: javascript

Como arredondar o valor de dentro de uma classe, no caso **39,54 % OFF** para **39 % OFF**, 
os valores são gerados pelo sistema?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Presumindo que você tem uma string com o número lá dentro pode usar assim:

(fiz vários passos só para ser mais claro)

```
var string = '39,54 % OFF';
var novaString = string.split('%'); // aqui fica com uma duas partes: ["39,24 ", " OFF"]
var arredondamento = parseInt(novaString[0], 10); // aqui converte a primeira parte para numero inteiro, arredondando-o para baixo
var resultado = arredondamento + '%' + novaString[1]; // aqui junta as duas partes novamente
alert(resultado);
```

[**Exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gwaty/)

No caso de ter o numero numa variável (que não me parece visto ter vírgula) pode usar o `Math.floor()`.

Se estiver a mudar texto no DOM, aqui fica um exemplo concreto usando o código acima numa função que pega todos os elementos e muda o texto:

```
function limparClasse(classe) {
    var elementos = document.querySelectorAll('.' + classe);
    for (var i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
        var elemento = elementos[i];
        var string = elemento.innerHTML;
        var novaString = string.split('%');
        var arredondamento = parseInt(novaString[0], 10);
        var resultado = arredondamento + '%' + novaString[1];
        elemento.innerHTML = resultado;
    }
}


limparClasse('vtex-cpShow'); // correr a função procurando a classe 'vtex-cpShow'
```

[**Exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8LFw3/)

---

#### Se usar expressões regulares pode fazer o código menor e usar assim:

```
function limparClasse(classe) {
    var elementos = document.querySelectorAll('.' + classe);
    for (var i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) 
        elementos[i].innerHTML = elementos[i].innerHTML.replace(/,.*%/, "%");
}
```

### [**Exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kzmv8/1)

Comment: Sergio, seria exatamente isso,
Mas no caso precisaria pegar o valor de uma classe ex:

<span class="desconto-de vtex-cpSave  vtex-cpShow ">15,0 % OFF</span> não seria de um valor fixo, desculpe pela falta de conhecimento rs. Obrigado!

Comment: @lucasinverso, vou adaptar a resposta

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Comment: @lucasinverso, juntei um exemplo à resposta para o caso de querer alterar em vários sítios.

Comment: Muito Obrigado Sergio, consegui adaptar, abraço.

Answer (score 3):

faltam informações dos tipos de dados que vc está tratando, mas vamos ver o que podemos fazer:

Caso seu valor numérico seja do tipo Float apenas um `parseInt(39.54)` deve resolver.
Caso seja uma string, `"39,54 % OFF"`, algo como

```
"39,54 % OFF".replace(/,[^%]+/, "")
```

resolverá seu problema.

A expressão regular procura por uma vírgula seguida de 1 ou mais caracteres que não sejam '%' e substitui por uma string vazia.

Answer (score 2):

Basta truncar o valor:

```
 function trunc (n) {
    return ~~n;
 }
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125715/javascript-trunc-function